# WebView inside RecyclerView, scrolling issue

Tags: android, html, webview, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with webView with is in RecyclerView item.
After click on YouTube video or twitter post, WebView is scrolled to top.
here is my layout of WebView item:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/postDetailItemWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and here is a layout of Activity where recycler is displaying:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ..../>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/postDetailRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/linear_recycler_anim"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<RelativeLayout..../>
```

WebView content is huge and it is more than screen size, that is why it needs scrolling. I have placed it inside RecyclerView becouse I have other items like: header and footer. Is there any fix for that or I have to place WebView outside RecyclerView as full screen view?

Comment: Did you got the solution for above ? @anddev

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView. And I found a solution eventually. 
This options helped me:

```
isFocusable = false
isFocusableInTouchMode = false
```

I hope they'll help you too.

Comment: We have to set these properties to WebView or recyclerView ?

Comment: I've set ```android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"```  these properties to ```webview``` in ```XML``` file

Answer (score -7):

WebViews support scrolling and shouldn't be places inside RecyclerView, try getting the WebView outside your RecyclerView